# Bounded linear operator, strange definition.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $L:X\to Y$ an linear operator. I saw that $L$ is bounded if $$\|Lu\|_Y\leq C\|u\|_X$$
for a suitable $C>0$. This definition looks really weird to me since such application is in fact not necessary bounded as $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$. So, is there an error in [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) ? And if the are true (what I supposed, since it's wikipedia), what is the interest to defined boundness as Lipschitz condition ? (it make no sense in fact...)

Comment: The term bounded is unfortunate. It should be named "continuous" instead and you can check that for linear application, continuity and uniform continuity are the same.

Comment: You can also understand this as saying that $||f||$ is bounded, where $||f||$ is defined as the smallest such $C.$ But as @anonymus put it, this term is unfortunate indeed.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. It's a valid question which has a reasonable answer. (It's quite likely to be a duplicate, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "bounded" has a special meaning (the one you wrote down) when it comes to linear operators on topological vector spaces (like normed spaces). It's a common definition in Functional analysis. It is not equivalent to the usual notion of a bounded map. (And it's not really helping to say this that it's an unfortunate term, since it is widely used in the pertaining literature).

See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator)

Comment: It definitely helps to say it's an unfortunate term.  When people first encounter a new term, they will try to associate it with what they already know.  Doing that with prior experience with what "bounded" means will lead to confusion, as shown by the OP.  Calling the term unfortunate posts a warning that the term probably doesn't mean what someone might think it does.

Comment: @Paul It's a definition, and used in every textbook on functional analysis I came to see by now, and for this reason it's futile to discuss whether it's an unfortunate term. Actually it's a good name (bounded on infinitely many directions) It's like the definition of an open ball of radius $r$. Whenever beginners are asked to show it's open you have a 99+ chance that someone says "well it's an open ball, so it's obvious, isn't it"? Of course you can call that unfortunate, as well, but it's a good name, too. It's the definiton which counts, not the associations people have hearing the term.

Answer (score 2):

This definition is not really trying to tell you that the values this operator spits out for each argument are always bounded by a given constant.

This definition says that the size (=norm) of the argument you plugged in in the domain, $\mid\mid u \mid\mid_X$ can only be "enlarged" or "diminished" by this much (this much being C) in the range, where its size is described as $\mid\mid Lu \mid\mid_Y$

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

Let $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ and $v\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $Av\neq 0$.

Then it is true that $$\lim_{s\to \infty} \|A(sv)\|=\|Av\|\lim_{s\to \infty} s=\infty.$$ 
However, there exists a $C>0$ such that
$$\frac{\|A(sv)\|}{\|sv\|}=\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}\leq C \qquad \forall s>0.$$
Now, if you set 
$$ \|A\| = \sup_{w\neq 0}\frac{\|Aw\|}{\|w\|}= \sup_{\|w\|=1}\|Aw\|$$
Then you can choose $C=\|A\|$ above. In this finite dimensional setting, we always have $\|A\|<\infty$ and $\|A\|$ is called an induced matrix norm. In *this sense*, $A$ is bounded because $\|A\|<\infty$. 
Note that
$$\|A\|=\inf\{C>0 \mid \|Aw\|\leq C\|w\|, \forall w\}.$$
Now, in infinite dimensional space, things are less nice. In particular, there exist some linear operators such that $\|A\|$ defined as above equals $\infty$. In which case $A$ is unbounded.

**Answer 2**

This way to define the boundness has sense. Indeed, let $\mathcal L(X,Y)$ the set of the linear application from $X\longrightarrow Y$. Then, $$|||L|||:=\sup_{x}\frac{\|Lx\|_Y}{\|x\|_X}$$ is a norm over $\mathcal L(X,Y)$, and thus, $$\{f\in \mathcal L(X,Y)\mid |||f|||<\infty \}$$
is a normed vector space. A good example to me would be to take an integrale operator,

\begin{align*}
T:L^p(\mathbb R^n)&\longrightarrow L^q(\mathbb R^n)\\
f&\longmapsto Tf= \int_{\mathbb R^n}K(t,\cdot )f(t)\mathrm d t.
\end{align*}

Then, if indeed $\|Tf\|_{L^q}\leq C \|f\|_{L^p}$ for a suitable $C$, then $T$ transform $L^p$ in $L^q$. So you can see the "boundness" as the fact that the operator is well defined. In the example I gave you, you can see it like the fact that $\|f\|<\infty $, implies that $Tf$ is well defined.